# Current version of logback can't read my JNDI entry

Tags: logback, jndi, websphere-liberty

I'm running a program on a WebSphere Liberty 21.0.0.11 with logging from logback 1.2.11.

I have a log output folder specified in my server.xml as:
<jndiEntry jndiName="logging/logPath" value="${server.output.dir}/logs"/>

In the logback.xml I read this entry with the line:
<insertFromJNDI env-entry-name="logging/logPath" as="logPath"/>

This worked in the old logback versions However in the new version of logback this name is not allowed as the name now must start with "java:".

So when I tried to change the line to:
<insertFromJNDI env-entry-name="java:comp/env/logging/logPath" as="logPath"/>

I get

```
14:37:59,720 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.InsertFromJNDIAction - Failed to lookup JNDI env-entry [java:comp/env/stibam/logPath] javax.naming.NamingException: CWNEN1000E:
```

Is there an error in my reading out of that JNDI variable?

Comment: CWNEN1000E indicates a lookup has been performed for a `java:` context on a thread that is not associated with a Java EE/Jakarta EE component (i.e Servlet or EJB, etc). The `java:` naming contexts are specific to Java EE/Jakarta EE components.

To overcome this, try using a ManagedScheduledExceutor from the concurrent-1.0 feature of Liberty, which uses managed threads and has access to Java EE context.

Comment: Also, the `jndiEntry` element is used to bind something into the global/server root naming context, which is outside the scope of any Java EE/Jakarta EE component. Any code in the server can look this up, but it would never be present in a `java:comp/env` context.  In order to bind something into `java:comp/env`, you would need to add an `env-entry` definition in a web.xml or ejb-jar.xml or use the `@Resrouce` annotation, and this it would be available to that specific component.

Comment: @HenStich I'm having the exact same Problem. Have you been able to figure it out?

Comment: Seems to me i have same problem after upgrading from logback from 1.2.11 to 1.3.3 and slf4j from 1.7.36 to 2.0.3, any suggestions?